# Unity: How can I control a Shadergraph effect on multiple enemies with the same prefab?

Tags: unity, shaders, effects, unity-shader-graph, prefabs

So I made a simple White Flash -> Dissolve effect with shader graph 2D, it's my 1st time using shaders.
I'm controlling the effect using a float inside the shader, with:

```
Material.SetFloat("FLOAT_NAME", 0-1f);
```

And I'm wandering how can a control only a single instance of my Shader without affecting all my enemies.

Example:
I have 20 enemies, all from the same prefab with the same material.
I want to be able to make 1 enemy dissolve whenever I shoot at him.

Comment: Have you looked into MaterialPropertyBlocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to mark as solved, but my problem was using the wrong reference, I referenced the Material directly, instead of the spriteRenderer material.

Comment: You'll be able to mark this as solved by clicking on the green checkmark on your question after a short delay. In the meantime, you could improve this question by showing the difference in code/inspector setup between what you were doing before, and what you did to fix it, so future users can learn from your example. Keep in mind that using the `renderer.material` getter creates a *copy* of the material, so be sure to clean up unneeded copies when you're done with them to reduce garbage and keep batching working for you.